# Error converting string of object to JSON/js object

Tags: javascript, json, string, object, typeconverter

im trying to convert a string into an object. I looked into it and everything says either use JSON.parse or eval. However when i try these to methods, my program fails, and i checked the debugger and its saying i am having an invalid expression: unexpected token k . Can anyone help me out?

```
router.post('/insertData', function (req, res) {
    var databaseName = req.body.DB , collection = req.body.collection, newData = req.body.data  ; 
    var test = JSON.parse(newData);
    var db = new Db(databaseName, new Server('localhost', 27017)); 
    db.open(function (err, db) {
        // Insert a document in the capped collection
        db.collection(collection).insert(test, { w: 1 }, function (err, result) {
```

[image]

Comment: what is that image supposed to be? if "{key:value}" is the actual value of `newData`, then it wont JSON.parse nor eval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSON](http://www.json.org/), short for JavaScript Object Notation, is a lightweight, language agnostic data-interchange format. In order to use `JSON.parse` on a JSON string, the string needs to be valid JSON. `"{key:value}"` is not a valid JSON string so the parser throws an error.

First, in JSON an object is an unordered set of name/value pairs where the name is a *string* and the value can be a *string*, *number*, *object*, *array*, `true`, `false`, or `null`.

The interesting thing is how JSON defines a string:

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, **wrapped in double quotes**.

So, what's wrong with your string `"{key:value}"`? Well, `key` is not a string, so the parser is immediately throwing an error when it gets to the "k". Also, once we fix `key` you'll find that `value` doesn't' mean anything either. You will need to pass the actual value here (a string, number, object, array value or `true`, `false`, `null` as mentioned above).

So, instead, you would want something like this:

```
var newData = '{"key":12345}';
var test = JSON.parse(newData);
console.log(test.key); // 12345
```

Comment: No, it gives an error while parsing. Wont do it at all

Comment: I know. My answer states that you need to give it "valid JSON." The snippet I provide works, so you need to ensure that your `newData` is a _valid JSON string` which the value you provide (`'{key:value}'`) is not. The value I provide, however, is ('{"key":12345}'). You need to fix your JSON string to parse it correctly.

Comment: well i have to pass it in as a string. "{key:value}", because im passing it via route. So how can i parse it to a valid json object?

Comment: O wait, i did {"key":12345} and it worked. Well i guess ill just have to add some client side validation. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way i can check if the JSON parse fails ? Like if(json.parse() != true) or something ?

Comment: @John Did you find a way to check JSON parse is success? I mean is it a valid json before converting?In my case, we have a error object which we can't convert into json.